# How to accept crypto payments to a website?

Tags: payment, website-integration

To start I have checked this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/how-to-allow-setup-crypto-transfers-payments-on-my-website), but the answers were unsatisfactory. Basically, I want to accept payments of ethereum, and bitcoin (these have different integrations). I want to setup this system from scratch (python, javascript). However, searching on the internet I get no clear answers. This is a simple problem (probably addressed multiple times). I would love to hear from anyone who has built such a system or anyone who has resources on how to integrate.


The blockchain is hosted on some servers, there is a protocol to download that blockchain (or parts, and check its validity), and parse the relevant transactions. Interacting with the blockchain is coin specific and there has to be respective endpoints. I may be simplifying this, but the fundamental problem is essentially this.


Can someone give *clear* answer to the issue of accept crypto payments (bitcoin and ethereum)? If no simple answer can be given, can I be directed to a developer community who would know the answer?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

> I would love to hear from anyone who has built such a system or anyone who has resources on how to integrate

BTCPay is an open source Bitcoin payment processor: https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Deployment/

> can I be directed to a developer community who would know the answer?

https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/discussions

Answer (score 2):

Yes I can confirm BTCPay Server is a solid and open source solution to accept cryptocurrency payments in your website, whether it is a native one or a CMS like Wordpress.
They have multiple ways to deploy:

1. Manual: You do it all by yourself but it is a pain. I tried myself and I managed to do it by myself, just by trying things.
2. Using "Configurator": Easiest way to deploy in my opinion. You just follow instructions on a nice GUI. They will generate a bash script at the end, to use on your VPS.
3. Docker deployment

After deployment, you could create Stores (multiple ones if you want), Apps (they can be for crowdfunding for example), Pay button (it will generate a code to paste to your website so people can pay you with BTC for example), and so much more...

BTCPay Server also supports multiple currencies and multiple crytocurrencies.

For deployment isntructions : https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Deployment/

For support during and after deployment : https://chat.btcpayserver.org/

Answer (score 2):

> I want to setup this system from scratch

Existing answers mention BTCPay which is not a system from scratch as OP is asking. It is a popular solution however it requires a node which means you also need a VPS to spin up a node and keep it running all the time, and it means it's more expensive to run the site.

To accept bitcoin on a website all you need to be able to do is present the user with an address to pay to. What happens after that can vary dramatically depending on your use case. It can be as simple as generating a few thousand key pairs upfront save them offline, import the generated addresses into a database, pull a new address for each order, mark the address as used and that's it.  You can use 3rd party APIs to check for transactions/payment, or you can import your addresses to a wallet.

If you're looking to automate things a bit more, for example do *something* after a payment is received then it gets more complicated and you're probably better off using something like BTCPay or building your own system using a node with JSON-RPC API and walletnotify -- which again means you need a VPS to have a 24/7 node to interact with.